# ms-access: how do i open a linked table on open?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i would like a linked datasheet (table) to open once access is opened. how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form with your linked table as it's record source.  Set the form to open automatically at database startup.

**Edit**: If you really, really feel you need to open the table directly instead of using a form ... look at [DoCmd.OpenTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220411%28office.11%29.aspx)  You could put your DoCmd.OpenTable statement in an autoexec macro.  Then it should run every time you open the database.

Comment: @hansup cant i just open the table?

Comment: You mean open the table in datasheet view?  Why?  Forms are the "proper" way for user interaction with data.

Comment: @hansup yes i just need the datasheet, i need a form at all

Comment: @hansup thank you very much, but that is the problem. can you walk me through the autoexec? i created the macro, where should i be putting the DoCmd function/?

Comment: OK.  I seldom do macros.  Looks like create a new macro, choose OpenTable in the Actions column and add your table name in the Table Name box.  Doesn't that work?  You must save the macro with the name autoexec.

Comment: A table datasheet is not a proper user interface for end users. Don't do this. It is a mistake. You will regret it and you'll run into problems. Take @HansUp's advice instead.